# FTP File Delivery Service

Tags: ftp, services

I am looking for a file delivery service that would allow any non-technical person at my company (or clients) to e-mail a large file to our FTP server and provide a download link.

I would like to be able to have the user specify which folder on the server the file gets sent to.

Is there software out there that does all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using YouSendIt.

Answer (score 0):

Why FTP?  Would a service like drop.io or box.net or [any of dozens of other collaboration sites] be better?  If large files are the problem, then email is probably going to constrain you more than the sites' limits.  Though I suspect you'd prefer to own the hardware.

You could get this functionality with Alfresco or Documentum and some customization--but man, that seems like a BIG hammer to solve this problem.

I've written Java to pop from an inbox on a schedule and feed an ECM system; surely what you're describing could be done in a similar fashion.  But I don't think you're going to find a packaged product to do exactly this for you.

Comment: I'm thinking somewhere along the lines of YouSendIt.com, but I want to host it on my servers, so I have more control over filenames, paths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org) would suit you needs.

Some [features](http://filezilla-project.org/client_features.php) that would matter for you:

- It is free
- Supported on various platforms
- Easy to use GUI (with [documentation](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Documentation))
- Supports bookmarks
- Supports Drag and Drop
- Resume and transfer of large files
- Supports Multiple languages (if you need that)